# adding parameters to LIMIT clause of a SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following prepared statement:

```
$sql =
     "PREPARE stmt_name FROM 
    'SELECT I.item_id, I.name , I.price, I.discounted_price, I.thumbnail_photo
    FROM item I
    JOIN sub_category SC
    ON I.sub_category_id = SC.sub_category_id
    JOIN category C
    ON C.category_id = SC.category_id
    WHERE C.category_id = ?
    LIMIT ?,? ' ; 

    SET @p1 = categoryId;
    SET @p2 = firstItem;
    SET @p3 = items_per_page;

    EXECUTE stmt_name USING @p1,@p2,@p3; "
```

which i changed to the following(wihtout using prepared statement)

```
$sql =

    'SELECT I.item_id, I.name , I.price, I.discounted_price, I.thumbnail_photo
    FROM item I
    JOIN sub_category SC
    ON I.sub_category_id = SC.sub_category_id
    JOIN category C
    ON C.category_id = SC.category_id
    WHERE C.category_id =' . (int)$categoryId;
```

I want to add parameters to the LIMIT clause
Ive gone through some sites, and it seems that adding parameters to the LIMIT clause in a select statement can be done only by using prepared statements. Can I have your opinions and suggestions please?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, why aren't you using PDO? You shouldn't need to manually prepare statements by hand..

Comment: I dont know how to do it using PDO. Could you please send me a link on that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using concatenation, rather than parameters, to build your new SELECT query.  If you'd like to continue down this road, you'd just append to your code:

```
. ' LIMIT ' . (int)$start . ', ' . (int)$number;
```

If you'd prefer to used a parameterized query, you'll need to use PHP's built-in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) extensions, or choose an abstraction layer with support for parameterized queries such as [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/).   Parameterized queries are often viewed as safer and cleaner than simply building queries through string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add parameters to the LIMIT
>   clause Ive gone through some sites,
>   and it seems that adding parameters to
>   the LIMIT clause in a select statement
>   can be done only by using prepared
>   statements.

So add the LIMIT. Why would a prepared statement only allow LIMITS? Its a SQL construct not a PHP construct.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use prepared statements to use limit. just add Limit...
for example

```
$sql='SELECT I.item_id, I.name , I.price, I.discounted_price, I.thumbnail_photo
    FROM item I
    JOIN sub_category SC
    ON I.sub_category_id = SC.sub_category_id
    JOIN category C
    ON C.category_id = SC.category_id
    WHERE C.category_id =' . (int)$categoryId.' LIMIT '.(int)$start.','.(int)$limit;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html